# In Rails when using the Devise gem how to create a user without email and password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my Rails app, Admins are the people who add users to the system. If the user doesn't have an email, a password won't be generated for him and he can't log in. But if the user have an email, a password will be generated. But the problem is, devise won't allow blank passwords. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can override them in your user model:

```
def password_required?
  false
end

def email_required?
  true
end
```

Edit:

```
def password_required?
   new_record? ? false : super
end
```

Comment: @EApubs, you should then accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @matanco One problem.. When I do this, password validations won't work!