# Ruby on rails - Devise registrations blank password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords

I'd like to build a web app based on ruby on rails. For authentication I am using the **devise** gem. Everything is good : I can create accounts, login, logout etc.

But here I have an issue. I'd like to be able to sign up without providing password but still have the ability to register with password for another account.

I've set the **password lenght** from 0 to 128 on config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.password_length = 0..128
```

But what are the next steps to do what I want?

Thank you

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857049/in-rails-when-using-the-devise-gem-how-to-create-a-user-without-email-and-passwo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I reply here as answer.

Thanks to Ammar Shah i figured out how to get users with password and users without password.

First of all create a file in **lib/devise/strategies** (create the folders) named **database_authenticatable.rb** with following code :

```
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    # Default strategy for signing in a user, based on their email and password in the database.
    class DatabaseAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        if password.blank?
          authentication_hash[:encrypted_password] = ''
        end
        resource  = mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)
        hashed = false

        if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
          remember_me(resource)
          resource.after_database_authentication
          success!(resource)
        end

        mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
        fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
      end
    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:database_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::DatabaseAuthenticatable)
```

Then in the **devise_create_user.rb** migration add :

```
t.string   :remember_token
```

Finally in **user.rb** model :

```
before_create :remember_value

def valid_password?(password)
    if password.blank?
        true
    else
        super
    end
end

def password_required?
    new_record? ? false : super
end

def remember_value
    self.remember_token ||= Devise.friendly_token
end
```

Thank you Ammar Shah for helping me !

Answer (score 1):

Reset password length in config/initializers/devise.rb to the default value and use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857049/in-rails-when-using-the-devise-gem-how-to-create-a-user-without-email-and-passwo) to make password optional.

Also, here is a complete implementation of [gradual engagement feature](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up) in devise wiki. It depends what exactly you want you achieve.

Comment: This works for registration. So I have my user in database with encrypted password empty. But i can't sign in without password. This raise an **invalid** error.

Comment: Of course you can't. You wanted to have an ability to just sign up your user without password and not sign in right? That is not how devise works, you need a way to set password for every user eventually, that is the reason I mentioned gradual engagement feature implementation.

Comment: Ok, but the gradual engagement feature implementation you mentionned ask the user to provide a password when he wants to confirm his account. But this isn't what I want.
So there is no way for me to use devise and sign in without password and without never asking for the user to provide a password?

Comment: Then you should create a password by yourself and let every user know about his/her password by sending an email to the email address provided, and on first login you should ask user to change his/her password. Because not having a password at all means anyone can login to anyone's account by just providing the email address for that account.

Comment: I just want users to be able to sign in with an empty/blank password. My problem isn't that anyone can login to anyone's account, i don't care about that actually ^^. Is there a way to do that with devise or not?

Comment: Well in that case you should use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662659/devise-authentication-without-password-using-just-username